# Is it possible to implement sumo logic in .net framework 4.5 with Console app? If yes how can we implement

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, sumologic

I am going to implement SumoLogic logging functionality in .NET Framework 4.5 without .NET Core. I have implemented almost but logs are not getting submitted into SumoLogic website. I think code missing something to implement or Sumologic does only support .NET Core.

Comment: You can use some tool to intercept network calls and see if your logs are sent to SumoLogic

Comment: Can you please mention which tools are you talking about.
Does Sumologic required .net core or not?

Comment: I do now know about Sumologic, but generally if you are calling a service which is online there are tool that you can use to capture the requests like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

There's this library that is supposed to help with getting C# logs to sumologic. I haven't used it personally, but it may be a step in the right direction.

https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-net-appenders